# Multiple object types in one ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, abstract-class, abstract, instanceof

I have an abstract class called User, a user can be created either as a Student type or as a Teacher type. I have made an ArrayList of users (of students and teachers) and what I am trying to do is call a method example depending on what the current object is an instance of:

```
for (User user : listOfUsers) {

  String name = user.getName();

  if (user instanceof Student) {

    // call getGrade();

  } else { // it is an instance of a Teacher

    // call getSubject();
  }
}
```

The problem I'm having is because it is an ArrayList of User objects, it can't get the Student type method, for example, getGrade(). However, because I am able to determine what the current user is an instance of, I'm curious as to whether or not it is still possible to call a specific method depending on what type of user it is.

Is this possible, or do I have to separate the user types into separate lists?

Please reply soon, many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the [downcast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downcasting):

> In object-oriented programming, downcasting or type refinement is the
>   act of casting a reference of a base class to one of its derived
>   classes.
>
> In many programming languages, it is possible to check through type
>   introspection to determine whether the type of the referenced object
>   is indeed the one being cast to or a derived type of it, and thus
>   issue an error if it is not the case.
>
> In other words, when a variable of the base class (parent class) has a
>   value of the derived class (child class), downcasting is possible.

Change your code to:

```
if (user instanceof Student) {

    ((Student) user).getGrade();

  } else { // it is an instance of a Teacher

    ((Teacher) user).getSubject();
  }
```

Comment: Great answer. Link, definition, and sample. Though perhaps you should do else `if (user instanceof Teacher) {}` and put an `else` at the bottom just for default behavior

Comment: Tnx  @Nappa The Saiyan!

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, my computer requested a restart in order to do some updates. Thanks for your prompt reply, and this did work, many thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to cast them to the class before using the method.

```
for (User user : listOfUsers) {

    String name = user.getName();

    if (user instanceof Student) {

        Student tmp = (Student)user;

        // call getGrade();
        tmp.getGrade();

    } else { // it is an instance of a Teacher
        Teacher tmp = (Teacher)user;
        // call getSubject();
        tmp.getSubject();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Store student and teacher objects in userList and then depending on the instanceOf condition call the respective class method by typeCasting to UserType

Consider below sample code

```
   abstract class User{

        public abstract String getName();
    }

    class Student extends User{

        @Override
        public String getName() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return "Student";
        }

        public String getGrade(){
            return "First Class";
        }

    }


    class Teacher extends User{

        @Override
        public String getName() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return "Teacher";
        }

        public String getSubject(){
            return "Java";
        }

    }

public class  Util {

public static void main(String[] args) {


        Student s = new Student();
        Teacher t = new Teacher();

        ArrayList<User> list = new ArrayList<User>();
        list.add(s);
        list.add(t);

        for(User user :list){
            if(user instanceof Student){
                System.out.println(((Student) user).getGrade());
            }

            if(user instanceof Teacher){
                System.out.println(((Teacher) user).getSubject());
            }
        }
}
}
```

Comment: It should look like this. Additionally the methods getSubject and getGrade should be moved to the superclass as getInfo or something similar. That would avoid the if-clause and instanceof

Comment: yes it can be possible ... but the  **inheritance** functionality says that child class gets features from parent and additionally it can have its own features . In the Above example class Student can have methods like getBranch() , getLastYearMarks() etc while Teacher can have getQualification() etc . in these cases we would still need if conditions to call specific methods